# JasperReport: footer field in xls participate in sorting

Tags: excel, jasper-reports, export-to-excel

I have such xls file generated by jasper:

[image: unsorted]

Bold **sum** is in `<pageFooter>` tag. After sorting it mixes up with data:

[image: sorted]

Is there any opportunity to make footer fields fixed and make them not participating in column sorting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately not, as this is Excel behaviour not Jasperreports behaviour and can't be controlled by the jasperreports.export configuration.

You could, instead, prevent the footer from being exported and convert the data to a table once in Excel which, although it's a manual step for the end-user, should resolve your problem.

The only other way is to ensure that, once exported to Excel, only the data rows are selected for sorting.

Regards,